# Fourier Uniqueness Theorem: Proof?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

*I need this as lemma.*

Given the Borel space $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Consider a complex measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{C}$$

Then one has:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{it\lambda}\mathrm{d}\mu(\lambda)=0\implies\mu=0$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to argue that if the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution is $0$, then the tempered distribution is $0$?

Comment: @paulgarrett this seems to be for a more general measure than ordinary Lebesgue measure, so classical Fourier analysis theorems won't apply.

Comment: To the op:  in what sense do you mean that integral? PV, or are you assuming that $e^{it\lambda}$ is in $L^1(\Bbb R, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Yep thats the problem: Not necessarily Lebesgue measure nor absolutely continuous measure nor positive measure.

Comment: @AdamHughes: It exists as Lebesgue integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|e^{it\lambda}|\mathrm{d}|\mu|(\lambda)=|\mu|(\mathbb{R})<\infty$

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AdamHughes: No problem, you're welcome!! :)

Comment: In fact every complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is regular.

Comment: @AdamHughes, depending on context, since it's not necessary that a "measure" be comparable to Lebesgue measure to qualify as a "tempered distribution", I'm not at all sure what's going on... but only that it's not entirely illegal to have measures (Dirac deltas, to say the least) that aren't comparable to Lebesgue... But maybe I don't understand the context...

Comment: @paulgarrett sorry if I was unclear, I just meant that quoting the theorem that the transform is injective, is basically saying "it's true because it's true," since that theorem is only widely-known in the form $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure (the classical setting).

Comment: @AdamHughes, ah, ok, now I understand the/your intention. Thanks for clarifying for me!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb {R})$ have compact support. Integrating by parts twice shows $\hat f (x) = O(1/x^2)$ at $\infty;$  hence $\hat f \in L^1.$ By the Fourier inversion formula, $f$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat f.$ Thus

$$\int_{\mathbb {R}} f(x)\,d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb {R}}\int_{\mathbb {R}}\hat {f}(t)e^{ixt}\,dt \,d\mu(x)  = \int_{\mathbb {R}}\hat {f}(t)\int_{\mathbb {R}}e^{ixt} d\mu(x)\,dt = 0.$$

Because the set of such $f$'s is dense in $C_0(\mathbb {R)},$ and the space of finite Borel measures form the dual space of $C_0,$ we see $\mu = 0.$

Comment: Duality rests on Riesz representation theorem. But afaik it is wrong for nonregular Borel measures, or?

Comment: Every finite Borel measure on $\mathbb {R}$ is regular.

Comment: Does it hold for complex measures too?

Comment: Yes, a complex measure is necessarily finite.

Comment: Sure but I found a result on regularity in Rudin for positive measures only...

Comment: A complex Borel measure $\mu$ is by definition regular iff $|\mu|$ is regular. (This is later in Rudin, on the chapter on complex measures.)

Comment: Aaaah right thanks alot!!